# How to Upload With ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, compilation

I am trying to upload my compiled web application to the Internet. I was told that all I need is the dll file which is supposed to go into the bin folder?  Is this true or do I need to upload both the dll file and the bin folder?

Also, is there a better way to build so that I don't have to intermix my image, css, and so on into my project folder? Maybe a way to copy the dll file to a bin folder and all my aspx pages?

I got it to work but it seems like I keep duplicating a bunch of files and I know eventually some problem will arise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Right-Click your project and Rebuild
- Right-Click your project and and click publish - I use "Publish to Files to Directory" to verify the right files are copied.
- Locate the published files where you specified on your system
- If you check the bin folder, all your references (.dll) should be inside
- Then upload the content of the published folder onto your site.

Comment: I'm publishing it locally, but I keep getting this weird error: The target "GatherAllFilesToPublish" does not exist in the project.  It doesn't point me to anything.  Do you know what's going on?

Comment: check this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/116d3562-99fb-45b0-acf9-b35bc393682e/

Comment: thanks the post by syed said that it's actually an error caused by the azure development tools for vs 2010. it turns out we have rename some target file and do a patch install.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is you use the Visual Studio menu Build -> Publish. Then you either export directly via FTP to your target server or to a local directory from where you copy the files to the web directory.

Only the required files are published.

Comment: i think im going to try to do it locally first. for some reason i keep getting a weird message like: The target "MSDEPLOYTESTCONNECTION" does not exist in this project error.